# What's RunDll32ShimW for in mscoree.dll?

Tags: .net, clr

I was looking at the exports in mscoree and notice that it exports a function named RunDll32ShimW.  The docs on MSDN [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms231918%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) aren't particularly helpful.  Anyone know what this was for?

I checked out the disassembly of it (it's not in the SSCLI) and it looks like it takes an assembly name and function, loads the DLL with mscoree!LoadLibraryShim, and calls the function on it.

Comment: Why the -1 here? nothing seems wrong with this question

Comment: Same kind of functionality as provided by RunDll32.exe, but for managed code.

Comment: Since you shouldn't call it, it doesn't really matter what it does.

Comment: I've been using this method in 3.5, since it's deprecated what should I use instead?

Answer (score 0):

The key sentence from the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms231918%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) is this:

> This function has been deprecated in the .NET Framework version 4.

As to what it does, I would make an educated guess that it calls `ShellExecute` or `CreateProcess` and was meant to be invoked by `rundll32.exe`.

Comment: Yeah, I linked to that MSDN article in my question...not super helpful.

Comment: I never even said I was going to use it, I was asking what it did.  Saying it's deprecated doesn't answer that question.

Comment: If I put the question in the past tense would that make you happier?  Also rundll32.exe is an EXE, this is exported from a DLL...not the same thing.  It's obviously meant to be called from rundll32.exe, not do the same thing as it.

Comment: @SteveN Yeah I get it now. Called from rundll32 and then passes the commands on to ShellExecute or CreateProcess.